# How to make factor names appear in ifelse statement in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have to following dataset. I want to create a column so that if there is a number in the unid column then in dat$identification I want it to say "unidentified" otherwise I want it to print whatever is there in the species column. So the final output should look like dat$identificaiton `x,y,unidentified,unidentified`. With this code it shows `1,2,unidentified,unidentified`.

Please note, for other purposes I want to use only the unid column for the !(is.na) part of the ifelse statement and not the species.

```
unid <- c(NA,NA,1,4)
species <- c("x","y",NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(unid, species)
df$identification <- ifelse(!is.na(unid), "unidentified", df$species)

#Current Output of df$identification: 
1,2,unidentified,unidentified

#Needed Output
x,y,unidentified,unidentified
```

Comment: Coerce to character with `as.character(df$species)` in the `ifelse`.

Comment: Great! If you can post it as an answer, I can formally upvote it.

Comment: See the edit to the answer, please. I think it will be worth your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can coerce the column of class 'factor`to class`character`in the`ifelse`.

```
df$identification <- ifelse(!is.na(unid), "unidentified", as.character(df$species))

df
#  unid species identification
#1   NA       x              x
#2   NA       y              y
#3    1    <NA>   unidentified
#4    4    <NA>   unidentified
```

**Edit.**

After the OP accepted the answer, I reminded myself that `ifelse` is slow and indexing fast, so I tested both using a larger dataset.

**First** of all, see if both solutions produce the same results:

```
df$id1 <- ifelse(!is.na(unid), "unidentified", as.character(df$species))

df$id2 <- "unidentified"
df$id2[is.na(unid)] <- species[is.na(unid)]

identical(df$id1, df$id2)
#[1] TRUE
```

The results are the same.

**Now time them** both using package `microbenchmark`.

```
n <- 1e4
df1 <- data.frame(unid = rep(unid, n), species = rep(species, n))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ifelse = {df1$id1 <- ifelse(!is.na(df1$unid), "unidentified", as.character(df1$species))},
  index = {df1$id2 <- "unidentified"
           df1$id2[is.na(df1$unid)] <- species[is.na(df1$unid)]
          },
  relative = TRUE
)
#Unit: nanoseconds
#    expr      min       lq        mean   median         uq      max  neval cld
#  ifelse 12502465 12749881 16080160.39 14365841 14507468.5 85836870    100   c
#   index  3243697  3299628  4575818.33  3326692  4983170.0 74526390    100   b 
#relative       67       68      208.89      228      316.5      540    100   a
```

On average, indexing is 200 times faster. More than worth the trouble to write two lines of code instead of just one for `ifelse`.